# Java Stream API to find words containing a list of characters

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am learning Java 8 and I am trying to make less use of the for loops and make my code look clean. I am trying to figure out a solution to the following problem .
I have a list of words and an array of characters for eg:

```
 List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
     words.add("go");
     words.add("me");
     words.add("boy");
     words.add("ate");
     words.add("mate"); 
     words.add("goal");

 char[] required_chars =  {'e', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'm', 'g', 'l'} ;
```

The output should be (go, me, goal) since these words contain characters/letters from the required_chars array. It should strictly use the elements from the array only.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You really need to attempt some code, I think it's unlikely someone will just write the whole thing for you.

Comment: @markspace i attempted to check every single character if it contains in each element of the list. but i am not able to achieve if all of them can together to get that word out as an output.

Comment: Simplest: `words.stream().filter(s -> s.matches("["+new String(required_chars)+ "]+")) .forEach(System.out::println);` If you want to avoid unnecessary repeated work, you can use `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("["+new String(required_chars)+ "]+");
    words.stream().filter(s -> p.matcher(s).matches()).forEach(System.out::println);` Starting with Java 11, you can use `.filter(p.asMatchPredicate())` instead of `.filter(s -> p.matcher(s).matches())`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FilterListStreamWithCharArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        words.add("go");
        words.add("me");
        words.add("boy");
        words.add("ate");
        words.add("mate");
        words.add("goal");

        char[] required_chars = { 'e', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'm', 'g', 'l' };

        Set<Character> requiredCharsAsSet = getBoxedChars(required_chars);

        List<String> filteredWords = words.stream().filter(eachElement -> {

            char[] eachElementsCharArray = eachElement.toCharArray();

            Set<Character> eachElemenstCharAsSet = getBoxedChars(eachElementsCharArray);

            if (requiredCharsAsSet.containsAll(eachElemenstCharAsSet)) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(filteredWords);

    }

    private static Set<Character> getBoxedChars(char[] charArray) {

        Set<Character> resultSet = new HashSet<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
            resultSet.add(new Character(charArray[i]));
        }
        return resultSet;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex based approach:

```java
String[] requiredChars =  {"e", "o", "b", "a", "m", "g", "l"};
String regex = "[^" + String.join("", requiredChars) + "]";
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(
    new String[] { "go", "me", "boy", "ate", "mate", "goal"
});
List<String> matches = words.stream()
    .filter(x -> !x.matches(".*" + regex + ".*"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(matches);
```

This prints:

```
[go, me, goal]
```

Explanation:

We form a regex alternation of individual characters of the alphabet which should *not* be present in any match:

```regex
[^eobamgl]
```

We can then stream your input list of words and remove any string which does match one or more of these blacklisted letters.

Comment: Instead of `(?:e|o|b|a|m|g|l)` you can simply use `[eobamgl]`. Instead of using negation, you can check whether the string is composed entirely of the specified characters with `matches("[eobamgl]+")`. Putting it all together makes [this one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65730326/#comment116223495_65730326) resp. two-liner if you don’t want to compose and parse the expression again for each match op. I’m not sure whether this is a “heavily regex based” approach; it’s rather basic regexp usage…

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the great feedback, and I have made the changes you suggested.  I think I was on my first cup of coffee when I posted my initial answer.

Comment: I still don’t get why you insists on the double-negation, instead of testing for `matches("[eobamgl]+")` (or `[eobamgl]*` if you want accept empty strings).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt with simple Java String and Stream api

```
class Scratch
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        words.add("go");
        words.add("me");
        words.add("boy");
        words.add("ate");
        words.add("mate");
        words.add("goal");

        List<String> result = words.stream()
                                    .filter(word -> isMatch(word))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    static boolean isMatch(String word) {
        Character[] required_chars =  {'e', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'm', 'g', 'l'} ;
        long count = Arrays.stream(required_chars)
                           .filter(ch -> word.contains(ch.toString()))
                           .count();
        return count == word.length();
    }
}
```